# rxJava2 CompositeDisposable in presenter

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, android-mvp

I'm migrating my app to the rxJava2 and would like to clarify some things.
In my BasePresenter class I do following:

```
@Override
public void attachView(T mvpView) {
    this.mvpView = mvpView;
    compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
}

@Override
public void detachView() {
    compositeDisposable.dispose();
    mvpView = null;
}
```

So if I call `compositeDisposable.dispose();` when I detach the view then `onNext()`, `onError()` or `onComplete()` are **not** going to be called and there is no reason to check `isViewAttached()` in `onNext()`?
Is this the right way of using CompositeDisposable in the presenter?

Comment: You don't have to check if you use standard static method (Observable.just/create/from) to create Observables. They check inside it already.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. CompositeDisposable is essentially what CompositeSubscription was in the previous version of rxJava.